# What is the next step if Canvas+Polyline is slow?

Tags: .net, wpf

Currently I use Polyline with many points which is placed on Canvas. But I am not satisfied with performance. What are the next step to improve performance? What should I use instead of Canvas+Polyline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much depends what you are trying to do, you should give more details. Does the polyline need any interaction, like hit testing?
If not, the fastest way might be to just draw the lines manually using DrawingContext.DrawLine in your Canvas's OnRender method (don't forget to freeze the Pen).